# String.replace in Java

Tags: replaceall

How can I transform the `string`

```
st = "[123, 123, 134,    90]"
```

into

```
s = "123 123 134 90"
```

Comment: Why not just replace all , [ and ] with ""... (note that if you use regex, `[` is a metacharacter and needs to be escaped with \ - but it is also an escape in java strings, so use \\\)

Answer (score 1):

replace " " with ""

replace "," with " "

replace "[" with ""

replace "]" with ""

Comment: yes [ with "" but i want to replace "," and "[" ,"]" so I used replaceAll(",\\]\\[","") but it didn't work so can you write the regex for me?

Comment: @agile you should do it like this `newString = replaceAll("\\[", "").replaceAll("\\]", "").replaceAll(","," ");`

Answer (score 0):

With Thanks to Maroun Maroun

`String st = "[123, 123, 134,    90]"`

```
String s = st.replaceAll("\\["," ").replaceAll("\\]"," ").replaceAll(","," ");
```